# Blur canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blur

I need to blur a canvas containing a simple animation.

I tried the [canvas filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) option but it's quite expensive (90% gpu usage on Chrome, 50% on Firefox).
I tried the css filter (54% gpu usage).

Are there other solutions? I prefer not to use third party libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript has the function .blur() have you tryed this ? i do not know how heavy it weigthts towards your cpu tho.

Comment: @JanWillem this method is the counter-part of focus method. I.e nothing to do with a graphical blur effect OP is looking for :)

Comment: Had your gpu something else to do at this time or can't 90% usage just be the sign it was effective? Other 2d solutions would imply ImageData manipulation and here it would be your cpu that you'd kill.

Comment: @kaido If I comment the blur function call the gpu usage fall from 90% to less than 10%